# netezza sql: compare all values of a field within a partition, find records with the N smallest differences

Tags: netezza

Caveats: no permissions to write/run PROCs, nor can I create/modify temp tables.

GIVEN a multiset table 'table1' with fields 'unique_primary_key','cust_num' and 'sale_date'.
THERE EXIST multiple records for each distinct value of 'cust_num', with varying values of 'sale_date'.

I NEED: ,after partitioning by 'cust_num', to find the minimum value of the difference between 'sale_date' for the record in question and 'sale_date' for every other record within the partition. Also, the 2nd smallest value of that difference, and the third smallest.

Each distinct 'cust_num' has anywhere from 3 to 75 records (all with different dates) in the table, so simply ordering by 'sale_date' within the partition and proceeding to explicitly compare the 'sale_date' value with every other record in the partition in not feasible.

I know how to easily do this in Excel using the INDEX function with MATCH as one of the arguments, etc., but I don't know of a comparable procedure in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a forward looking or backward looking measure of difference in dates, I think you can do this with a simple lag/lead approach.

```
 select * from table1 order by cust_num, sale_date;
 UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY | CUST_NUM | SALE_DATE
--------------------+----------+------------
                  7 |        1 | 2014-10-06
                  2 |        1 | 2014-10-12
                  5 |        1 | 2014-10-14
                  1 |        1 | 2014-10-17
                  4 |        1 | 2014-10-19
                  3 |        1 | 2014-10-22
                  6 |        1 | 2014-10-25
             100008 |        5 | 2014-10-07
             300002 |        5 | 2014-10-13
             100006 |        5 | 2014-10-15
             200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18
             200004 |        5 | 2014-10-20
             100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23
             100007 |        5 | 2014-10-26
```

Then...

```
SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
   CUST_NUM,
   SALE_DATE,
   lead(sale_date,1) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date) lead1,
   lead(sale_date,2) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date) lead2,
   lead(sale_date,3) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date) lead3
FROM table1
ORDER BY CUST_NUM,
   SALE_DATE

   PK   | CUST_NUM | SALE_DATE  |   LEAD1    |   LEAD2    |   LEAD3
--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------
      7 |        1 | 2014-10-06 | 2014-10-12 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-17
      2 |        1 | 2014-10-12 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-19
      5 |        1 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-22
      1 |        1 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-25
      4 |        1 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-25 |
      3 |        1 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-25 |            |
      6 |        1 | 2014-10-25 |            |            |
 100008 |        5 | 2014-10-07 | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-18
 300002 |        5 | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-20
 100006 |        5 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-23
 200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-26
 200004 |        5 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-26 |
 100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-26 |            |
 100007 |        5 | 2014-10-26 |            |            |
(14 rows)
```

In the more likely case that you want it to be an ABS of the date difference, my brain still wants to use lag & lead, but is streatching to its sad capacity and has to piece it together in a much more complicated fashion like this:

```
WITH foo AS
   (
      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lead(sale_date,1) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lead(sale_date,1) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lead(sale_date,2) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lead(sale_date,2) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lead(sale_date,3) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lead(sale_date,3) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lag(sale_date,1) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lag(sale_date,1) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lag(sale_date,2) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lag(sale_date,2) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT UNIQUE_PRIMARY_KEY pk,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         lag(sale_date,3) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)                  rel_sales_date,
         ABS(sale_date - lag(sale_date,3) over (partition BY cust_num ORDER BY sale_date)) day_delta
      FROM table1
   )
SELECT pk,
   cust_num,
   sale_date,
   rel_sales_date,
   day_delta,
   day_rank
FROM (
      SELECT pk ,
         cust_num,
         sale_date,
         rel_sales_date,
         day_delta,
         dense_rank() over (partition BY pk ORDER BY day_delta nulls last) day_rank
      FROM foo
   )
   foob
WHERE day_rank <= 3
ORDER BY cust_num,
   sale_date,
   day_rank


   PK   | CUST_NUM | SALE_DATE  | REL_SALES_DATE | DAY_DELTA | DAY_RANK
--------+----------+------------+----------------+-----------+----------
      7 |        1 | 2014-10-06 | 2014-10-12     |         6 |        1
      7 |        1 | 2014-10-06 | 2014-10-14     |         8 |        2
      7 |        1 | 2014-10-06 | 2014-10-17     |        11 |        3
      2 |        1 | 2014-10-12 | 2014-10-14     |         2 |        1
      2 |        1 | 2014-10-12 | 2014-10-17     |         5 |        2
      2 |        1 | 2014-10-12 | 2014-10-06     |         6 |        3
      5 |        1 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-12     |         2 |        1
      5 |        1 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-17     |         3 |        2
      5 |        1 | 2014-10-14 | 2014-10-19     |         5 |        3
      1 |        1 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-19     |         2 |        1
      1 |        1 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-14     |         3 |        2
      1 |        1 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-12     |         5 |        3
      1 |        1 | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-22     |         5 |        3
      4 |        1 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-17     |         2 |        1
      4 |        1 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-22     |         3 |        2
      4 |        1 | 2014-10-19 | 2014-10-14     |         5 |        3
      3 |        1 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-25     |         3 |        1
      3 |        1 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-19     |         3 |        1
      3 |        1 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-17     |         5 |        2
      3 |        1 | 2014-10-22 | 2014-10-14     |         8 |        3
      6 |        1 | 2014-10-25 | 2014-10-22     |         3 |        1
      6 |        1 | 2014-10-25 | 2014-10-19     |         6 |        2
      6 |        1 | 2014-10-25 | 2014-10-17     |         8 |        3
 100008 |        5 | 2014-10-07 | 2014-10-13     |         6 |        1
 100008 |        5 | 2014-10-07 | 2014-10-15     |         8 |        2
 100008 |        5 | 2014-10-07 | 2014-10-18     |        11 |        3
 300002 |        5 | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-15     |         2 |        1
 300002 |        5 | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-18     |         5 |        2
 300002 |        5 | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-07     |         6 |        3
 100006 |        5 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-13     |         2 |        1
 100006 |        5 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-18     |         3 |        2
 100006 |        5 | 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-20     |         5 |        3
 200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-20     |         2 |        1
 200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-15     |         3 |        2
 200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-13     |         5 |        3
 200003 |        5 | 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-23     |         5 |        3
 200004 |        5 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-18     |         2 |        1
 200004 |        5 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-23     |         3 |        2
 200004 |        5 | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-15     |         5 |        3
 100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-20     |         3 |        1
 100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-26     |         3 |        1
 100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-18     |         5 |        2
 100005 |        5 | 2014-10-23 | 2014-10-15     |         8 |        3
 100007 |        5 | 2014-10-26 | 2014-10-23     |         3 |        1
 100007 |        5 | 2014-10-26 | 2014-10-20     |         6 |        2
 100007 |        5 | 2014-10-26 | 2014-10-18     |         8 |        3
(46 rows)
```

Hopefully that helps, and if not I at least got some mental exercise this Friday afternoon.